# How to disable button Angular?

Tags: angular

I tried this function:

```
public hireDisableForm() {
    const dis =  this.person.birthDate == '' || this.person.passportNumber == '' || this.person.passportSerie == '';
    return (!dis) ? null : dis;
  }
```

It return me `true`, I checked this in `console.log()`.

Using:

```
<button class="hire1" [disabled]="hireDisableForm()">Save</button>
```

It does not disable button.

Comment: is it happening on form load?

Comment: I use dialog window. Form is placed in dialog window.

Comment: That does not matter, if its a form it should work'

Comment: Does not work, I see that function return `true`

Comment: well if its returning true it should work... make sure it is returning true, another way to debug is just return true no conditions, and make sure function is being called!

Comment: How are you checking if the button is `disabled` or not? The reason I'm asking is since I don't see any other events being registered to the button, how do you know if it is truly `disabled`?

Comment: I tried simplify as `[disabled]="true"`

Comment: disabled means 'not clickable' - you won't necessarily see any style change unless you put some in i.e `button[disabled] {background-color:red}`. If you inspect the element in the dev tools you should see that it is disabled.

Comment: create a plunkr of this with stripped styling. It should work. I just tested it on plain html with angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it in so complicated way! You can do it simpler:

```
public hireDisableForm() {
    return !(this.person.birthDate && 
           this.person.passportNumber && 
           this.person.passportSerie);
}
```

Comment: No matter, it return also true, but button is not disabled.